# Pivoting to calculate average with 1's and 0's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

I need help building a pivot query from a data set that looks like this:

[image]

1 indicates the employee spoke with someone or the location and 0 indicates they haven't spoke with someone

I want to return a calculation the % of contacts spoken to and the % of locations spoken to by employee and then manager so the table would look like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to pivot this so it calculates the percentage for each employee's assigned contacts and then the percentage for each manager's employee's assigned contacts?

Comment: honestly i haven't the slightest idea where to start because i am trying to average 1's and 0's

Comment: Can you create a sql fiddle?

Comment: @wewesthemenace i'm not very proficient at this, i'm running off a prebuilt table from the company with limited SQL knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a pivot if you only have two categories.  Try case statements:

```
Select employee as [Name]
  ,count(case when ContactType = 'Individual' and SpokeTo = 1 then LocationName end) * 100.0/ NULLIF(count(case when ContactType = 'Individual' then LocationName end), 0) as IndividualContacts
  ,count(case when ContactType = 'Location' and SpokeTo = 1 then LocationName end) * 100.0/ NULLIF(count(case when ContactType = 'Location' then LocationName end), 0) as LocationContacts
from MyTable
group by Employee
```

Note the `*100.0` is important to avoid integer division (or you can cast explicitly to `decimal`).  The `NULLIF` is optional unless you have some employees that were not assigned any contacts of one type or another - then you must include it to avoid division by 0 errors.